# why java.lang.IllegalStateException: no transaction pending and how to solve

Tags: android

I developed one android application.Its working fine for our device and and most of the devices.But some of the users sent error report.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no transaction pending
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:610)
at com.footy.fixture.FixtureActivity$ProgressTask.doInBackground(FixtureActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

Why this happends for some devices.Which type of error is this?...How can I solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called `SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction()` without first calling `SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction()`. So you're trying to close a transaction which doesn't exist. Inspect your code, or post the relevant snippets here if you can't see what's wrong.

Comment: i used both endtransaction and begintransaction in that doinbackground() method........

Comment: Well, apparently you are not always calling them in the correct order. Post your code.

Comment: i can post 600 characters only...so how could i?